# How to set up Thinktecture Authorization Server

Tags: .net, authorization, thinktecture-ident-server

I need to implement OAuth 2.0. Thanks to google, I found Thinktecture Authorization Server. It's an open source project that allow you to...blah blah.

And then, I jump to the wiki page, watch the Initial Setup Video at here https://vimeo.com/69300053.
I follow the instruction, but after click on Configure Server, browser always redirect to this link.

https://idsrv.local/issue/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aauthorizationserver&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fAdmin%252fHome&wct=2014-01-04T08%3a08%3a54Z

1. Anyone have experiences with this issue?
2. Anyone have experiences with set up Thinktecture Authorization Server, please give me an advice. I'm new to OAuth2.0 and don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to it as well, but you need to configure it to use an identity server provider such as google/thinktecture identity server/linkin/facebook or others.  So in other words, you need something to say "who" is logged in, that authorization server trusts, and then authorization server will provide the tokens with scopes.

You have to modify the \Configuration\identityModel.services.config file to point to the correct url of what ever identity provider you want to use.

If you want to have your own identity provider, thinktecture also has Identity Server v2 that will work great.  https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2

Comment: Thanks, I find the solution. Eventhough, I got another issue... Anyway, thanks again.